# Query to check if multiple results already exist in the database

Tags: mysql, database

I know the title of the question is a little akward but I can't express myself better.

I have three tables which goes like this:

```
Driver       
id_driver    name
   1         Hamilton
   2         Alonso
   3         Räikkönen

Group_Driver
id_group     id_driver        
   1            1
   1            2
   1            3

Group
id_group     name
   1         team name
```

In my app I can allow one person to choose 3 drivers for their team (that's sorted already, it's 3, no more, no less) but I need to check if the next person to make a team will choose the same three someone else already picked. Meaning that Person 1 can pick for his Group 1 drivers 1, 2 and 3. The next person can chose drivers 1, 3 and 4 and so on but I can't let them pick 1, 2, 3 again as a combination if someone else (person 1) already picked them, how do I do that with mySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this query returns any value means that a group already exists with the same picked drivers (for the example, drivers 3, 4 and 6)

select id_group from group_driver where id_driver in(3,4,6)group by id_group having count(id_group)=3

Comment: Now that I see the query it's really simple and I should have been able to figure it out. My mysql skills are rusty! Thank you